# Context Free Grammar for English Sounding Names

Tags: random, context-free-grammar, auto-generate

I am currently writing an application that will generate random data; specifically, random names.  I have made some decent progress, but am not satisfied with many of the generated names.  The problem lies in my production rules, which I've attached to the bottom of this post.

The basic idea is: *consonant, vowel, consonant, vowel*, but some consonants themselves map to vowels (such as *b< VO >*).

I have not fully created the rules yet, but the final idea would follow the format shown below.  However, rather than finishing it, I would like to make a better basis for the production rules.

I have tried to find a reference that discusses either: a CFG already created for English-sounding words, or an English reference that disassembles the basic format of letter combinations for words.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a useful resource to help me advance farther than I already have.  Does anyone know of a place I should look, or a reference I can look at?

ALSO: in your opinion, do you believe a context-sensitive grammar might work better?

```
    //the following will deal with single vowels and consonants
var CO = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','qu','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'];
CO.probabilities = [2.41,4.49,6.87,3.59,3.25,9.84,0.24,1.24,6.5,3.88,10.9,3.11,0.153,9.67,10.2,14.6,1.58,3.81,0.242,3.19,0.12];
CO.name = "CO";
var VO = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
VO.probabilities = [21.43,33.33,18.28,19.7,7.23];
VO.name = "VO";

var LETTER = ['<VO>','<CO>'];
LETTER.probabilities = [38.1,61.9];
LETTER.name = "LETTER";

//the following deal with connsonant pairs
var BH = ['c','p','r','s','t']; //the fisrt part of a th, ph, sh, pair (before H)
BH.probabilities = [20,10,20,25,25];
BH.name = "BH";

var BL = ['b','c','f','g','p','s']; //before letter l
BL.probabilities = [10,20,10,10,25,25]
BL.name = "BL";

var COP = ['<BH>h','<BL>l'] //consonant pairs
COP.probabilities = [50,50];
COP.name = "COP";

//this is a generic syllable, that does not take grammar rules into consideration
var SYL = ['<CO><VO>','<VO><CO>','<CO><VO><VO>'];
SYL.probabilities = [50,20,30];
SYL.name = "SYL";

//the following deal with mid word syllablse
var CLOSED = ['<CO><VO><CO>','<CO><VO><CO><CO>'];
CLOSED.probabilities = [75,25];
CLOSED.name = "CLOSED";

var OPEN = ['<CO><VO>','<CO><CO><VO>'];
OPEN.probabilities = [60,40];
OPEN.name = "OPEN";

var VR = ['<VO>r']; //vowel-r
VR.probabilities = [100];
VR.name = "VR";

var MID = ['<CLOSED>','<OPEN>','<VR>'];
MID.probabilities = [33,33,33];
MID.name = "MID";

//the following will deal with ending syllables
var VCE = ['<VO><CO>e','<LETTER><VO><CO>e'];
VCE.probabilities = [75,25];
VCE.name = "VCE";

var CLE = ['<CO>le'];
CLE.probabilities = [100];
CLE.name = "CLE";

var OE = ['tion','age','ive']; //other endings
OE.probabilities = [33,33,33];
OE.name = "OE";

var ES = ['<VCE>','<CLE>','<OE>','<VR>']; //contains all ending syllables
ES.probabilities = [40,40,20];
ES.name = "ES";

var rules = [CO,VO,BH,BL,COP,LETTER,SYL,CLOSED,OPEN,VR,MID,VCE,CLE,OE,ES];

//These are some highly-defined production rules
var streetSuffix = ['road','street','way','avenue','drive','grove','lane','gardens','place','crescent','close','square','hill','circus','mews','vale','rise','mead'];
streetSuffix.probabilities = [15,15,5,10,5,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7,2.7];
var states = ['Alabama','Alaska','American Samoa','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado','Connecticut','Delaware','Florida','Georgia','Guam','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois','Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Marshall Islands','Maryland','Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana','Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York','North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Palau','Pennsylvania','Puerto Rico','Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah','Vermont','Virgin Island','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming'];
var cityNewWordSuffix = ['city','town',''];
var cityEndWordSuffix = ['polis','ville','ford','furt','forth','shire','berg','gurg','borough','brough','field','kirk','bury','stadt',''];

var siteSuffix = ['com','org','net','edu'];

/**
    This will generate a random name of Length length
*/
function generateRandomName() {
    //string will be random length of CO VO pattern for now
    var result;

    result = "<COP><VO><MID><VO><ES>";

    while (hasNonTerminal(result)) {
        result = replaceFirstNonTerminal(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here are a few words generated by the machine in its current state:

> "cheiroene",
>   "sloeraase",
>   "sledehgeute",
>   "rhaorenone",
>   "rheerisute",
>   "chaereehe",
>   "sletraoege",
>   "sluureese",
>   "chaheyleete",
>   "chierauhe",
>   "ploclooate",
>   "glawofhaice",
>   "thanisgoage",
>   "slelaodose",
>   "blaereode",
>   "shihudeife",
>   "slaereene",
>   "pleheaele",
>   "rhepicsaile",
>   "ploeruoge",
>   "sliareuhe",
>   "thaereafe",
>   "thaaraeke",
>   "cheoreate",
>   "shofetniote",
>   "phiraoese",
>   "clilniueye",
>   "slepceikede",
>   "cligloueohe",
>   "phitleoime",

Comment: Why do you allow consonants to map to vowels?

Comment: Part of the idea of this particular implementation is to pair letters which appear at least somewhat commonly together.

Comment: My first reaction is to remove the vowels from all the productions of consonants and add a new symbol `<SYL>` (syllable) which can be `<CO><VO>` or `<CO><VO><CO>` or one of the common consonant-vowel pairs. A name is one or more repetitions of `<SYL>`.

Comment: Yes, a syllable is a great idea!  I'll implement that and comment back in a minute.

Comment: I've implemented the <SYL>, and have added a few more production rules along the same lines (edited in the original post).  It is getting better, I've also added some words it's made in its current state.

Comment: As a completely different idea, have you considered using a general-purpose model such as a Markov chain and training it on a large list of real names? There is a good introduction to Markov chains in [Section 15.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20080512091003/http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/sec153.html) of Programming Pearls by Jon Bentley, and here is a [Python example](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/06/generating-pseudo-random-text-with-markov-chains-u/) (it uses a word-level model, but changing it to a letter-level model should be straightforward).

Comment: That is an interesting idea, and something I will look into in the future.  However, at this point, I am interested in developing this project without using any real names at all.

Comment: Just for fun, here is a Markov chain implementation in Python that trains on names from the US census: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=execute_python3_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNU1wR013YVlrcVk. Sample names: Violeen, Margarenci, Tanne, Donne, Charah, Anth, Laton, Cythie, Contina, Cecia.